# Add tuple values as values for key in dictionary

Tags: python

I have data which is a list of multiple tuples i.e.

`data = [('Bidder', 112, 'apple_id'),('Deal', 131, 'android_id')]`

I want to make a list of dictionaries  like

`output_data = [{NAME : 'Bidder',ID : 112,DEVICE_TYPE : 'apple_id'},{NAME : 'Deal',ID : 131,DEVICE_TYPE : 'android_id'}]`

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Looking at your code, this looks an awful lot like you might wanna use namedtuple: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to create list of dictionaries.

```
data = [('Bidder', 112, 'apple_id'),('Deal', 131, 'android_id')]

list_of_dicts = [{"NAME" : entry[0], "ID" : entry[1], "DEVICE_TYPE" : entry[2]} for entry in data]

print(list_of_dicts)

print(type(list_of_dicts))

print(type(list_of_dicts[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data=[('Bidder', 112, 'apple_id'),('Deal', 131, 'android_id')]
keys=['NAME','ID','DEVICE_TYPE']
output_data = [{i:j for i,j in zip(keys,k)} for k in data]
print(output_data)
```

Output:

```
[{'NAME': 'Bidder', 'ID': 112, 'DEVICE_TYPE': 'apple_id'}, {'NAME': 'Deal', 'ID': 131, 'DEVICE_TYPE': 'android_id'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the list of keys with each `tuple` in `data`, this will create pairs of `tuple`s `(key, value_from_data)` which you can convert to dictionary using `dict()`

```
data = [('Bidder', 112, 'apple_id'), ('Deal', 131, 'android_id')]
keys = ['NAME', 'ID', 'DEVICE_TYPE']
output_data = [dict(zip(keys, t)) for t in data]
print(output_data) # [{'NAME': 'Bidder', 'ID': 112, 'DEVICE_TYPE': 'apple_id'}, {'NAME': 'Deal', 'ID': 131, 'DEVICE_TYPE': 'android_id'}]
```